# Display Joomla 3.x category without its articles

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Is there an option when displaying a joomla 3.x category (via a menu) to NOT show any of its articles? Either in Blog or in List style.

Comment: What's left if not the articles? Are you asking how to show a list of sub-categories?

Comment: Did you try filling in the leading, intros and links as 0 in the blog view?

Comment: Sorry, this works as you said. I had to change the category type from list to blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dedicated view to display all article categories from a admin selected root in core Joomla.  When selecting the menu type, under the articles accordion header, called List All Categories.  You can select Root for the top level category field to didplay all article categories.

Comment: Yes, this is it. I hadn't tried this option. Thank you.

Comment: But when I do that (i.e. List All Categories), is there an option to NOT display subcategories also? What I'm trying to do is to only show the category HTML and nothing else from decedent articles or categories.

Comment: In the edit menu view, select the Categories tab, and the SubCategory Levels filter is what you want.

Comment: This does not work, because the dropdown menu there has the options 1,2,3,4,5 All but not NONE.

Comment: so you want to display a list of subcategories of root with 0 sublevels? Make a page with the text "root" that will be quicker.

Comment: @GEORGE TARANTILS - You want to select one.  If you have the Root as the top category level, displaying 0 sub-categories would give you a blank page.  Since you only want the first sub-level of categories under Root, select 1 for desired results.